# Why does my React Component Export not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was just getting into react and trying it out for myself. After hours of configuring webpack just to get a hello world on my screen I thought I could get going now but after trying to render another component from a file the next problem.

My main file is app.js, which renders everything:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Hello} from './hello';

ReactDOM.render(
   <Hello/>,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The Hello component comes from my hello.js in the same folder:

```
import React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return (
           <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
       )
    }
}

export default Hello;
```

It was rendering fine when I was doing everything just in app.js without the import/export. It also compiles fine. But there are a lot of errors now in the console. So what am I missing?

Thanks

Gerd

Comment: Your Hello component is using `export default` so you'll want to remove the braces - `import Hello from './hello';`

Comment: There's a bug as well when it just stops working even it was working perfectly and even when you can open the exported function by ctrl+clicking the variable.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Because your export is `default` you don't need braces around your import component name:

```
import Hello from './hello';
```

[Here's a verbose technical article](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) from Axel Rauschmayer on the final ES6 modules syntax that you might find useful.

[And here's a slightly less techy post](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f) about the same topic.

Comment: thanks a lot for not only getting a rookie up and running but also making him understand what the actual difference is.

Comment: "you don't need braces" should really be "you can't use braces".  Export default must be imported without braces; you can export-deault only one thing per module.  Export regular must be imported with braces, where you list all the exports from the module, by name.  You CAN export a name regularly, and then also default.  Then you can import it either way.

Answer (score 17):

when you import the default class you use

```
import ClassName from 'something';
```

and when you import other classes you use

```
import {ClassName} from 'something';
```

an example:

in hello.js file

```
import React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return (
           <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
       )
    }
}

class Other extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return (
           <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
       )
    }
}
export default Hello;
export Other;
```

in other file

```
import Hello, {Other} from './hello';
```

tip: you could also import the default class with other name

```
import Component, {Other} from './hello';
```

Comment: This is an excellent example however the Other component would also need it's own export statement.

Comment: When you export default, you export a  value, not anything with a name.  Actually, it has a name, 'default'.  So, you import from hello.mjs, and all exports are on the variable 'default', and when you say 'import Hello from hello.mjs', you give it a name, like Hello = default;

If you export non-default, say 'export function Gbye...', you're really exporting default.Gbye .  That has a name, 'Gbye', that is required, in order to find it on the variable 'default', among other things exported non-default.  So, import {a, Gbye, c} from hello.mjs is like 'const {a, Gbye, c} = default;  Sortof.