# React import error when using export default

Tags: reactjs

I have a

- `menu-item.component` in `src/components/menu-item/menu-item.component.jsx`
- `directory.component` in `src/components/directory/directory.component.jsx`.

In `menu-item.component`:

```js
import React from "react";

import withRouter from "react-router-dom";

import "./menu-item.styles.scss";

export const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size }) => (
  <div className={`${size} menu-item`}>
    <div
      className="background-image"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`
      }}
    />
    <div className="content">
      <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
      <span className="subtitle">Alışverişe Başla</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

// export default MenuItem;
```

with this, the import statement `import { MenuItem } from "../menu-item/menu-item.component";` in `directory.component.jsx` works well. When I remove `export` from function definition and instead add `export default MenuItem;` at the bottom, the `npm start` fails with:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/directory/directory.component.jsx
> Attempted import error: 'MenuItem' is not exported from '../menu-item/menu-item.component'.

I'm new to react and following the exact code from a tutorial and it works well in the videos. Why this fails?

Comment: Please check this for detailed answer, hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619405/why-does-my-react-component-export-not-work

Comment: I see, sorry I have done a search but didn't see this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the brackets

```
import MenuItem from "../menu-item/menu-item.component"
```

When you do an 'export default', you dont need to be specific about the name when importing to get the default import (you can import it as Item or MenuI, for example, but always starting with a capital, to let React knows it's still a component);

Also, remove the `export` before the const declaration you're using `export default`